# How to add add request parameter to every Angular.js $http request (to start a xdebug session for example)

Tags: angularjs, rest, xdebug

My hybrid application is based on AngularJS and uses a php REST api.

I would like to debug the php api directly from my Angular app instead to use REST console or Postman. It would save a lot of time especially for POST and PUT requests.

In order to do so I would need to add a parameter to each request like so:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/contacts?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
```

Can I config $http to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use httpInterceptor for that (official $http [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) contains more info)

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('xdebugInterceptor', function($q) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success

      // !!! adjust the config object
      // add request param XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
      // it will be added to every made request

      config.params = config.params || {};
      config.params.XDEBUG_SESSION_START: "PHPSTORM";

      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },


    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

// make this conditional so you use it only in DEV mode
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('xdebugInterceptor');
```

Comment: Ok for the structure of it. When you write `// add request param XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM`how do you actually do that? That's unclear in the doc how you can access th eurl or params. Thanks

Comment: Ok great @tomastrajan !

Comment: Ok, I added the actual code to the example, works for me, it's added for every request

Comment: Also you can use interceptors for central unwrapping of responses (eg: return response.data), and central error handling (like show some notifications) in 'responseError'

Comment: You may consider editing the name of your stack overflow question to how to: "How to add add request parameter to every Angular.js $http request" so that it better describes the problem and the solution so more people can find it.

Comment: Good suggestion. Done!

Comment: I realized the way it was implemented would override all your other query params you may want send with the request so I adjusted checking for the  "config.params" object

Comment: Good point ! I had only this query param so I had not noticed. thx

Comment: Guys, how you deal with AngularJs template request? I mean, html one. Every request now have this parameter bundled in and html request messed up. Is there any way to filter it out? I haven't find a way how, though I've tried to. thanks!

Comment: I had similar problem, what I did was that I decoraded $http service with my own methods like `apiGet`, `apiPost`... and then I set a flag on those requests so I could use simple if statement in interceptor to not add stuff on those requests