# How to intercept every Ajax Request with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I need to intercept every Ajax Request to verify if the server responded with a `401 Unauthorized` because the session expired and redirect to the login page so the user don't think the app stopped working. I can do this the following way using JQuery:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
   if(xhr.errorCode == 401 || xhr.responseText === "unauthorized") {
    location.href = "/Login";
   }
});
```

How can i do this with Angular JS?

Comment: :( you are risking getting downvoted... You should explain what you have looked up in Angular and shown failing options..

Comment: Give a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors. You can do this during the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the $interceptor on application config()

```
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$q',  function($location, $q) {
            return {
                'request': function(request) {    
                    return request;
                },
                'responseError': function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 401) {
                        // do stuff
                    }
                    // otherwise, default behaviour
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        }]);
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `httpInterceptor`. Very similar question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761140/how-to-add-add-request-parameter-to-every-angular-js-http-request-to-start-a-x/31761353#31761353) awhile ago. You should then be interested in `'response'` hanndler and add your specific logic there.

Answer (score -1):

Make a single function that you use to make all your calls, you only have to handle errors in one place instead of many

```
function makeCall(obj, cb) {
    $http({
        method: obj.method,
        url: obj.url,
        data: obj.data || {}
    }, function(res) {
        // non error statuses get handled here
    }, function(res) {
        // error statuses get handled here
    })
}
```

Comment: This is only for one request he needs to do it for every request

Comment: See edited version. Use the function for all your calls - write your error handling block there.

Comment: Its still a bad solution because $http service already contains httpInterceptros to handle that.