# How can i maintain Oauth token throughout the project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have one issue. I have a project which is created in MVC and AngularJs using Apis. I want to apply the OAuth token with all Apis.

I will follow the below steps :

1. First login from the panel.
2. Maintain OAuth token in the header of each page.
3. Use that OAuth token from the header and pass from each web API request.

If somewhere I am wrong please let me know. How can I do?

Please share if anyone has done before.

Comment: You realize that having the token in the header would mean that anyone could view the source on your web app and then have the token they could use to call the api?  You might want to consider a cookie or a session variable instead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. Do you have any sample project for this issue or any reference link where I can find a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service/factory that will make all API requests from your app.
It's just a wrapper of $http. call it something like ApiService.

This service would read the token from where ever it stored (header, cookie...) and append it to every request.

This very much like the pattern $http handles [XSRF protection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. Do you have any sample project for this issue or any reference link where I can find a sample project?

Comment: Here is an [example doing it with httpInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761353/6767060). And here is an example of [wrapping the $http in a custom service](https://gist.github.com/isRuslan/e0273e8540b9dd041555)